# How to trim text in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

So when I type `uptime` in Linux terminal it gives me something like the this:

```
00:27:29 up 2 days, 10:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

But, all I really want is the load average information. How can I trim the text to

```
load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

I'm really not sure which command to use for something like this. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

a simple

```
 uptime | sed 's/.*load/load/'
```

should do the trick

Comment: simply put, I get the uptime result (the whole string), then I just say "substitute the string that ends with the word load, with the word "load" only"

Comment: Oh ok. So then 's' is the entire string (uptime) that is "fed" into sed?

Comment: Whoops, no sorry, s stands for substitute. the concept of "entire string which ends with "load"" is given by the regular expression "whatever series of characters (given by the construct ".*") followed by the four characters "l" "o" "a" "d". So in synthesis it could be translated as: edit (sed) by making a substitution ("s") of the regular expression /.*load/ with the expression "load"

Answer (score 2):

With a simple `cut` command,

```
uptime|cut -d',' -f3,4,5
```

**Output** will be:

```
load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

Through awk,

```
$ uptime | awk -F"  +" '{print $NF}'
load average: 0.19, 0.16, 0.21
```

`-F"  +"` sets the Field Seperator value to two or more spaces. So awk splits each line according to two or more spaces. And this `print $NF` will print the value of last column.

Comment: You're welcome.. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Another way with **`sed`**:

```
uptime | sed 's/.*  //'
```

Substitute everything from beginning till the last occurrence of `2 continuous spaces` (including) with nothing.